# How do i compare EditText Value to textview Int

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext, compare

I am building an app for imaginary Gym, where people can buy a particular number of trial class.

What I am trying to do is to have and EditText area, where we put number of trial classes, that displays in a textview like ( 5/0) the first number is the value of edittext. and second value is text view, what i want when a button is pressed that it should increase the (0) value and when it reaches to 5, button should stop working.

here is my code:

```
   package com.example.ross.classcards;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText classesBought;
    TextView classesDetails;
    Button doneClasses, buyClasses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        doneClasses = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        buyClasses = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyClasses);

        buyClasses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                classesBought = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Bought_Classes);
                classesDetails = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_classes_record);
                classesBought.getText().toString();
                classesDetails.setText(classesBought.getText() + " / 0 ");
            }
        });

        doneClasses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int bought = Integer.parseInt(classesBought.getText().toString());
                int done = 0;

                if (done < bought){
                    done++;
                    classesDetails.setText(bought + " / " + done);
                } else {
                    classesDetails.setText("Done");
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? its not workking

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing:

```
editText.getText().toString().equals(textview.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Edson. the problem is that i am not able to create a logic to do so